# Ты часто слушаешь боярские/боярсские песни?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? Это, если что, прилагательное.

> Ты часто слушаешь боярские/боярсские песни?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Ты часто слушаешь **боярсские** песни?*

Образование прилагательного: ***Боярск/ий — боярс/ск/ий.***

**ДВЕ БУКВЫ СС** (правило)

Две буквы СС в относительном прилагательном пишутся **при усечении** основы существительного **перед суффиксом СК.**

Здесь происходит **усечение буквы К** в основе исходного существительного перед суффиксом СК (обычно в иноязычных названиях) и удвоение СС на стыке усеченной основы на С и суффикса СК: ***Дамаск – дамас/ск/ий, этруск – этрус/ск/ий.***

В данном случае нужно различать: ***боярский и боярсский.***

Comment: Надо писать *Боярский*.

Comment: Но в справочнике же написано, что там, чтоб это происходило, перед *-ск* должна быть гласная. Из-за этого я и спросил.

Comment: Есть общие тенденции, но есть и частные решения. В конечном итоге ориентируются на то, чтобы  сделать понятным значение прилагательного.